# Spring / Kafka - configuration properties priorities - application.properties, bean(ProducerFactory)

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

`Kafka` configuration properties:
Can i have the same property "key"(and maybe different "value") in
 
(1) application.properties,
(2) bean(ProducerFactory/ProducerConfig) and

If yes, who is the *"last-win"*?

P.S Yes, i know, test it! But it will also be handy to have this question/answer on SO.

**EDIT:**
Example:
(1) spring.kafka.producer.properties.enable.idempotence=true
(2) props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "false");
 
With props defined as:

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Object, Object> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Show your properties and configuration and a more specific question. In general, as described in the Spring Boot documentation, generic kafka properties will override Spring Boot well-known kafka properties.

Comment: Thanks Gary, added an example of what i meant.

Comment: config/producer.properties is just a file. Kafka libraries don't natively read that, so you'd have to load it yourself (possibly via a bean). And it's not clear where `props` is defined, but the bean would likely be loaded after the Spring config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boot property (1) is only used when Boot auto-configures the producer factory for you. Since you are defining your own producer factory `@Bean` (2), Boot's is disabled and the properties are ignored.

If you want to use the Boot `application.properties`, simply remove your `producerFactory` `@Bean` and let Boot configure the producer factory for you.

I have no idea what `config/producer.properties` (3) is.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell, i have edited my question and removed(3).